# Leaflet MarkerCluster: Is it possible to open multiple cluster-groups?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have recently started working with leaflet. I found the great plugin leaflet markercluster. I am currently trying to open several clustergroups at the same time. Unfortunately I can't find anything on google.

I have several cluster groups and draw connections from one marker to another. The user should be able to open both cluster groups to which the drawn line goes:

[image: My example]

Therefore my question: Is there a function for this that I have to switch on or is opening several groups at the same time not provided at all?

Comment: I want to spiderfy the secound group when I click on it. So i checked the spiderfy function in leaflet.markercluster-src.js. There it says that unspiderfy() of the last group is always called before a new spiderfied is called. So I think that I have to change the .js file and have to remember the opened groups to close them again later on

Answer (score 3):

Okay I have experimented a little bit on it now ;)

In the leaflet.markercluster-src.js I created an array called `_spiderMan[]` which is filled with the clicked objects in the function spiderfy.

```
spiderfy: function() {
  if (this._group._spiderfied === this || this._group._inZoomAnimation) {
    return;
  }

  var childMarkers = this.getAllChildMarkers(null, true),
    group = this._group,
    map = group._map,
    center = map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._latlng),
    positions;

  // this._group._unspiderfy();  //deactivated
  var markers = markers + childMarkers;
  _spiderMan.push(this);  //new          

  if (childMarkers.length >= this._circleSpiralSwitchover) {
    positions = this._generatePointsSpiral(childMarkers.length, center);
  } else {
    center.y += 10; 
    positions = this._generatePointsCircle(childMarkers.length, center);
  }

  this._animationSpiderfy(childMarkers, positions);
},
```

Then I have created a for loop which runs through the array and calls `_spiderMan[i].unspiderfy(zoomDetails)` every time. I built this loop into the function `_unspiderfyZoomAnim` for testing. Means every time you zoom in or out, all open groups are summarized.

```
_unspiderfyZoomAnim: function(zoomDetails) {
  if (L.DomUtil.hasClass(this._map._mapPane, 'leaflet-touching')) {
    return;
  }
  this._map.off('zoomanim', this._unspiderfyZoomAnim, this);
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < _spiderMan.length; i++) {
    _spiderMan[i].unspiderfy(zoomDetails);
  }
  _spiderMan = [];
},
```

In addition, the following lines must be deactivated in the `unspiderfy` function:

```
unspiderfy: function(zoomDetails) {
  /// <param Name="zoomDetails">Argument from zoomanim if being called in a zoom animation or null otherwise</param>
  // if (this._group._inZoomAnimation) {
  //    return;             
  // }
  this._animationUnspiderfy(zoomDetails);

  // this._group._spiderfied = null;        
},
```

So it's now possible to open and close mutiple cluster-groups but this is only a workaround and I think it will have some bad effects somewhere because of commenting out or removing code lines.

I think someone with more experience in JS and this plugin should find a better and more comfortable solution ;).

Comment: If this worked for you, you ought to accept your own answer, as that will help others who read this question in the future (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO!

Unfortunately, the spiderfication management in Leaflet.markercluster plugin currently assumes a single cluster can be spiderfied at a time.

See also [danzel's comment in Leaflet.markercluster issue #744](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/744#issuecomment-286922970) (Spiderfy all clusters at a particular view):

> Leaflet.MarkerCluster only supports having one cluster spiderfied at the moment, so this would need a bit of work to support.

Answer (score 1):

May be you will get a better answer if you give a use case ...

However, it is safe to say that there is no function you can switch on to open several groups in one click.

From a usability point of view, it does not make much sense as the basic behaviour of MarkerCluster is to click on one icon to zoom in and expand the group you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-clusters-methods :

> - **spiderfy**: Spiderfies the child markers of this cluster
> - **unspiderfy**: Unspiderfies a cluster (opposite of spiderfy)

So once you have references to the clusters you want to "open" (spiderify) at the same time, just call their `.spiderify()` method.

e.g. if the desired clusters are in variables `cluster1` and `cluster2`:

```
cluster1.spiderify();
cluster2.spiderify();
```

See also https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#getting-the-visible-parent-of-a-marker and https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#clusters-methods about how to get references to the clusters.

Comment: I want to spiderfy the secound group when I click on it. So i checked the spiderfy function in leaflet.markercluster-src.js. There it says that unspiderfy() of the last group is always called before a new spiderfied is called. So I think that I have to change the .js file and have to remember the opened groups to close them again later on

Comment: That's information you should add to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you can keep open multiple clusters, but only one for each group. My guess is that your markers all belong to a single group. In which case you can't keep open multiple clusters.

You could opt for a hover approach, which opens a cluster if you hover over it.

```js
const mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([48.550, 8.207], 6);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);

const markers = L.markerClusterGroup({zoomToBoundsOnClick: false});
[[47.5617, 7.5504], [47.5255, 7.6163], [47.5691, 7.6355],
 [49.4922, 8.3922], [49.5306, 8.5172], [49.4547, 8.5062]]
  .map(latLng => L.marker(latLng))
  .forEach(marker => markers.addLayer(marker));
mymap.addLayer(markers);

markers.on("clustermouseover", a => a.layer.spiderfy());
markers.on("clustermouseout", a => a.layer.unspiderfy());
```

```css
html, body, #mapid { margin: auto; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately I have to display information about the marker when I click on it. This mouseover event makes it a little harder to catch and hit a marker ;D

Comment: @ajl31701 You could change the event to "clusterclick". But unfortunately you can't have open multiple clusters for a single group without modifying the JavaScript code.